# UPDATE mysql with array without foreach

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I insert `array` into `mysql` without any loop and make query for each array:

```
$albumid = $_GET['id'];
$gettrack = $_POST["songtrack"];
$gename = $_POST["songname"];
$getlength = $_POST["songlength"];
$getprice = $_POST["songprice"];

$data = array();
$size = count($_POST["songname"]);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $size ; $i++){
  $data[$i] = array(
     "albumid"     => $albumid, 
     "track"     => $gettrack[$i], 
     "name"    => $gename[$i], 
     "length"    => $getlength[$i], 
     "price"       => $getprice[$i]
  );
}

$values = array();
foreach($data as $datas){
  $values[] = "('{$datas['albumid']}','{$datas['track']}', '{$datas['name']}', '{$datas['length']}', '{$datas['price']}')";
}

$values = implode(", ", $values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `song` (albumid, track, name, length, price) VALUES {$values};";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

**Now i want update mysql with something like this**, but i have no idea, googled and found similar topics but all of theme update mysql with array with `foreach` loop, i don't want to make query with every array, any solution?

can i change above code to update mysql?

Comment: Did you run this code?

Comment: yes, this `insert into` mysql, it works fine, i looking for a solution for `update` mysql like above code, without any loop. @u_mulder

Comment: Unfortunatelly, mysql doesn't support something like bulk update. But another soultion could be begin transaction before first update and commit after last query. It should be faster.

Comment: @CodeGodie no it's not possible duplicate! this topic use `for each` as well.

Comment: @pedram ok i will remove it, but can you clarify more so that we clearly understand what you need

Comment: @CodeGodie i explained 3 times, look at my above code, it `insert` into mysql without repeat query for each array, as you see `mysql query` is outside the loop, now i want something like this to update data, without using any loop. because i don't want to repeat query for each item! is it clear?

Comment: @VirCom can you explain more about this: `begin transaction before first update and commit after last query` ?

Comment: I will write an answer for you.

Comment: You don't need the both loops just build `$data` and `$values` in the same loop if you need both. It would be easier if your form inputs were in the form of `name="song[0][songtrack]"` and `name="song[0][songname]"` etc...

Comment: I see what the problem is. It wasnt too clear. Youre trying to `UPDATE` multiple rows at once, not multiple columns... Read this: https://stuporglue.org/update-multiple-rows-at-once-with-different-values-in-mysql/

Comment: @CodeGodie maybe duo my bad english  sorry.. anyway, this link..look like it's my solution, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysqli extension.
So one of the possible options is use multi_query function, generate to string all update statements separatelly and run it during one transaction:

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE....
UPDATE....
UPDATE....
COMMIT;

It should be faster that run updates one by once.

Another solution could be build complexity UPDATE statement. For example:

UPDATE song
SET
    Field = CASE value1 WHEN condition1 THEN value1
WHEN condition2 THEN value2 ...

Or complex IF ELSE statement.

Last possibility is using custom procedure or function to evaluate correct value.

I thins there's no other way.